# problem related to enumeration in c++. is that a known issue already?

Tags: c++, enums

I have found a problem with enum in C++. I wonder if that is a known issue.

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch,
   system("pause") or input loop */

using namespace std;

enum color { red = 8, green = 7, blue };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    color r = red, g = green, b = blue; 

    cout << r << " " << g<< " " << b << " " <<endl;

    switch (b) {
        case red:
            cout << "a bad thing happened" << endl;
            break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

running the program you get:

8 7 8
a bad thing happened

Comment: It works as intended. Not sure if it's really a problem.

Comment: What did you expect the value of enumerator blue to be? By language specification it is 8.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com)

> If the first enumerator does not have an initializer, the associated
>   value is zero. For any other enumerator whose definition does not have
>   an initializer, the associated value is the value of the previous
>   enumerator plus one.

So basically blue is green +1 => 8 which is equal to red (8)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `b` is 8, same as `r`. In enums, if you don't specify the exact value for an enumerator, it will be one more than the previous one, 7+1=8 in your case.